# Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException when I try to relation two entities of different modules

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, module, zend-framework2, repository

I've got the next error in my development:

[image]

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]

 The target-entity Game\Entity\UserEntity cannot be found in 
'Game\Entity\ChallengeRosterEntity#user'.
```

I have two modules:

- User
- Game

In these modules I have defined several entities where one of them is relationed with other entity which belongs to other module.

**\Game\Entity\ChallengeRosterEntity.php**

```
<?php
namespace Game\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use User\Entity;

/** @ORM\Entity
 *  @ORM\Table(name="challenge_roster")
 *  @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Game\Repository\ChallengeRosterRepository")
 */
class ChallengeRosterEntity{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ChallengeEntity", inversedBy="challengeRoster")
 *
 **/    
protected $challenge;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserEntity", inversedBy="userInRosters")
 *
 **/    
protected $user;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable = true)
 */ 
protected $points;

/**
 * Fecha y hora de creación del roster del desafío por parte del usuario
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable = false)
 */ 
protected $date;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BasketballPlayerStatsEntity")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="players_roster",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="challenge_roster_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="basketball_player_stats_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 **/    
protected $basketballPlayers;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set points
 *
 * @param integer $points
 * @return ChallengeRosterEntity
 */
public function setPoints($points)
{
    $this->points = $points;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get points
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getPoints()
{
    return $this->points;
}

/**
 * Set date
 *
 * @param \DateTime $date
 * @return ChallengeRosterEntity
 */
public function setDate($date)
{
    $this->date = $date;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get date
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDate()
{
    return $this->date;
}

/**
 * Set challenge
 *
 * @param \Game\Entity\ChallengeEntity $challenge
 * @return ChallengeRosterEntity
 */
public function setChallenge(\Game\Entity\ChallengeEntity $challenge = null)
{
    $this->challenge = $challenge;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get challenge
 *
 * @return \Game\Entity\ChallengeEntity 
 */
public function getChallenge()
{
    return $this->challenge;
}

/**
 * Set user
 *
 * @param \Game\Entity\UserEntity $user
 * @return ChallengeRosterEntity
 */
public function setUser(\Game\Entity\UserEntity $user = null)
{
    $this->user = $user;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get user
 *
 * @return \Game\Entity\UserEntity 
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->basketballPlayers = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add basketballPlayers
 *
 * @param \Game\Entity\BasketballPlayerStatsEntity $basketballPlayers
 * @return ChallengeRosterEntity
 */
public function addBasketballPlayer(\Game\Entity\BasketballPlayerStatsEntity $basketballPlayers)
{
    $this->basketballPlayers[] = $basketballPlayers;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove basketballPlayers
 *
 * @param \Game\Entity\BasketballPlayerStatsEntity $basketballPlayers
 */
public function removeBasketballPlayer(\Game\Entity\BasketballPlayerStatsEntity $basketballPlayers)
{
    $this->basketballPlayers->removeElement($basketballPlayers);
}

/**
 * Get basketballPlayers
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getBasketballPlayers()
{
    return $this->basketballPlayers;
    }
}
```

**\User\Entity\UserEntity.php**

```
<?php
namespace User\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Game\Entity;


/** @ORM\Entity
 *  @ORM\Table(name="user")
 *  @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="User\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class UserEntity{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */ 
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length = 20, nullable = false)
     */ 
    protected $nick;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length = 100, nullable = false)
     */ 
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length = 100, nullable = true)
     */ 
    protected $thumb;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable = false)
     */
    protected $totalRetodones;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable = false)
     */ 
    protected $challengeWon;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable = false)
     */
    protected $points;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable = false)
     */ 
    protected $spentRetodones;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length = 100, nullable = true)
     */
    protected $twitterAccount;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length = 100, nullable = true)
     */
    protected $facebookAccount;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="StatusEntity", mappedBy="users")
     **/
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserEntity", mappedBy="refered")
     **/
    protected $referedBy;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserEntity", inversedBy="referedBy")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="refered_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $refered;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserEntity", mappedBy="myFriends")
     **/
    protected $friendsWithMe;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserEntity", inversedBy="friendsWithMe")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_friends",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="friend_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     **/
    protected $myFriends;   

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ChallengeEntity", inversedBy="userChallenger")
     *
     **/
    //protected $usersChallenger;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ChallengeEntity", inversedBy="userChallenged")
     *
     **/
    //protected $usersChallenged;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ChallengeRosterEntity", inversedBy="user")
     *
     **/
    protected $userInRosters;

     /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->status = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->referedBy = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->friendsWithMe = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->myFriends = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nick
     *
     * @param string $nick
     * @return UserEntity
     */
    public function setNick($nick)
    {
        $this->nick = $nick;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nick
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNick()
    {
        return $this->nick;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return UserEntity
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set thumb
     *
     * @param string $thumb
     * @return UserEntity
     */
    public function setThumb($thumb)
    {
        $this->thumb = $thumb;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get thumb
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getThumb()
    {
        return $this->thumb;
    }

    /**
     * Set totalRetodones
     *
     * @param integer $totalRetodones
     * @return UserEntity
     */
    public function setTotalRetodones($totalRetodones)
    {
        $this->totalRetodones = $totalRetodones;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get totalRetodones
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getTotalRetodones()
    {
        return $this->totalRetodones;
    }

    /**
     * Set challengeWon
     *
     * @param integer $challengeWon
     * @return UserEntity
     */
    public function setChallengeWon($challengeWon)
    {
        $this->challengeWon = $challengeWon;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get challengeWon
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getChallengeWon()
    {
        return $this->challengeWon;
    }

    /**
     * Set points
     *
     * @param integer $points
     * @return UserEntity
     */
    public function setPoints($points)
    {
        $this->points = $points;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get points
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getPoints()
    {
        return $this->points;
    }

    /**
     * Set spentRetodones
     *
     * @param integer $spentRetodones
     * @return UserEntity
     */
    public function setSpentRetodones($spentRetodones)
    {
        $this->spentRetodones = $spentRetodones;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get spentRetodones
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getSpentRetodones()
    {
        return $this->spentRetodones;
    }

    /**
     * Set twitterAccount
     *
     * @param string $twitterAccount
     * @return UserEntity
     */
    public function setTwitterAccount($twitterAccount)
    {
        $this->twitterAccount = $twitterAccount;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get twitterAccount
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTwitterAccount()
    {
        return $this->twitterAccount;
    }

    /**
     * Set facebookAccount
     *
     * @param string $facebookAccount
     * @return UserEntity
     */
    public function setFacebookAccount($facebookAccount)
    {
        $this->facebookAccount = $facebookAccount;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get facebookAccount
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFacebookAccount()
    {
        return $this->facebookAccount;
    }

    /**
     * Add status
     *
     * @param \User\Entity\StatusEntity $status
     * @return UserEntity
     */
    public function addStatus(\User\Entity\StatusEntity $status)
    {
        $this->status[] = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove status
     *
     * @param \User\Entity\StatusEntity $status
     */
    public function removeStatus(\User\Entity\StatusEntity $status)
    {
        $this->status->removeElement($status);
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Add referedBy
     *
     * @param \User\Entity\UserEntity $referedBy
     * @return UserEntity
     */
    public function addReferedBy(\User\Entity\UserEntity $referedBy)
    {
        $this->referedBy[] = $referedBy;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove referedBy
     *
     * @param \User\Entity\UserEntity $referedBy
     */
    public function removeReferedBy(\User\Entity\UserEntity $referedBy)
    {
        $this->referedBy->removeElement($referedBy);
    }

    /**
     * Get referedBy
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getReferedBy()
    {
        return $this->referedBy;
    }

    /**
     * Set refered
     *
     * @param \User\Entity\UserEntity $refered
     * @return UserEntity
     */
    public function setRefered(\User\Entity\UserEntity $refered = null)
    {
        $this->refered = $refered;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get refered
     *
     * @return \User\Entity\UserEntity 
     */
    public function getRefered()
    {
        return $this->refered;
    }

    /**
     * Add friendsWithMe
     *
     * @param \User\Entity\UserEntity $friendsWithMe
     * @return UserEntity
     */
    public function addFriendsWithMe(\User\Entity\UserEntity $friendsWithMe)
    {
        $this->friendsWithMe[] = $friendsWithMe;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove friendsWithMe
     *
     * @param \User\Entity\UserEntity $friendsWithMe
     */
    public function removeFriendsWithMe(\User\Entity\UserEntity $friendsWithMe)
    {
        $this->friendsWithMe->removeElement($friendsWithMe);
    }

    /**
     * Get friendsWithMe
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getFriendsWithMe()
    {
        return $this->friendsWithMe;
    }

    /**
     * Add myFriends
     *
     * @param \User\Entity\UserEntity $myFriends
     * @return UserEntity
     */
    public function addMyFriend(\User\Entity\UserEntity $myFriends)
    {
        $this->myFriends[] = $myFriends;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove myFriends
     *
     * @param \User\Entity\UserEntity $myFriends
     */
    public function removeMyFriend(\User\Entity\UserEntity $myFriends)
    {
        $this->myFriends->removeElement($myFriends);
    }

    /**
     * Get myFriends
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getMyFriends()
    {
        return $this->myFriends;
    }

    /**
     * Set userInRosters
     *
     * @param \User\Entity\ChallengeRosterEntity $userInRosters
     * @return UserEntity
     */
    public function setUserInRosters(\User\Entity\ChallengeRosterEntity $userInRosters = null)
    {
        $this->userInRosters = $userInRosters;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userInRosters
     *
     * @return \User\Entity\ChallengeRosterEntity 
     */
    public function getUserInRosters()
    {
        return $this->userInRosters;
    }
}
```

Doctrine 2 has the next configuration in each file.

**\Game\config\module.config.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2014 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace Game;

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
/*             'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ), */
            // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
            'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/juego',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Game\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
            'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
        'aliases' => array(
            'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Game\Controller\Index' => 'Game\Controller\IndexController'
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'game/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/game/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
    // Doctrine config
    'doctrine' => array(
            'driver' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
                            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                            'cache' => 'array',
                            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
                    ),
                    'orm_default' => array(
                            'drivers' => array(
                                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                            )
                    )
            )
    ),
    // Placeholder for console routes
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

**\User\config\module.config.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2014 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace User;

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
            'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/user',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'User\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
            'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
        'aliases' => array(
            'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'User\Controller\Index' => 'User\Controller\IndexController'
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'user/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/user/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
    // Doctrine config
    'doctrine' => array(
            'driver' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
                            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                            'cache' => 'array',
                            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
                    ),
                    'orm_default' => array(
                            'drivers' => array(
                                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                            )
                    )
            )
    ), 
    // Placeholder for console routes
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change targetEntity="UserEntity" to targetEntity="User\Entity\UserEntity"

Comment: I have changed targetEntity = "UserEntity" to targetEntity = "User\Entity\UserEntity" or targetEntity = "\User\Entity\UserEntity" and with targetEntity = "GameEntity" the same and it doesn't work :( And I have the same error

Comment: Same error message?  You must have something else going on because using the fully qualified class name for targets will work.  Make sure you change them all.  Make sure that both modules are being loaded.  I know how Symfony 2 does it.  Have not looked at ZF2.

Comment: Yes, same error message. If I comment the attributes which are relationated with other modules, it works, so modules are being loaded.

Comment: Might try deleting any cache.  I find it difficult to accept that you are still getting "The target-entity Game\Entity\UserEntity" even though you changed the target to "User\Entity\UserEntity".  Try UserEntityXXX.  If the error message does not change then it's a cache issue or you might be editing the wrong file..

Comment: Finally ... It works!!! I have cleaned all the cache but it didn't work!!! So, I have change the name of UserEntity to UserEntity2 and ... It works!!! Thank you so much @Cerad for your help!!!